# Text and Input elements seem to disappear on IE (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm building a page (It's a Landing Page) with Bootstrap 3,
everything went great until I tried the page in IE, where for some reason, every text and input on the page just disappear, I mean really DISAPPEAR.
I can see them for a split second and then it looks like something that loads after those elements just covers them up,
I've tried fixing and searched for an answer but couldn't find one, I hope someone here could point me in the right direction!
First of all I don't know which version of IE this is (It's the deafault version of Windows 7 I presume),
The HTML is pretty long so I would provide a link to the actual site:
http://adam-hatzayar.besaba.com/ (The text is in hebrew)
I will provide the CSS here:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/opensanshebrew.css);

#bg {
  background-image: url(../img/line-middle.jpg);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

#head {
  background-image: url(../img/head2.jpg);
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color:#ccc;
}

#header-text h1 {
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight:900;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, -2px 0 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, 0 -2px 0 #000, 1px 1px #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000;
}

#header-text p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 200%;
}

#call-link {
  padding:10px;
}

.container {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Hebrew', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
  width: 950px;
  }
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.form-spec {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-spec form {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  text-align: right;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .move-btn {
   margin-right: 122px;
  }

  #header-text h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight:normal;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 0 #000, -0px 0 0 #000, 0 0px 0 #000, 0 -0px 0 #000, 0px 0px #000, -0px -0px 0 #000, 0px -0px 0 #000, -0px 0px 0 #000;
  }

  #header-text p {
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 0 #000, -0px 0 0 #000, 0 0px 0 #000, 0 -0px 0 #000, 0px 0px #000, -0px -0px 0 #000, 0px -0px 0 #000, -0px 0px 0 #000;
  }

  #bg {
    background: #FFF;
  }

  #head {
    background: #FFF;
  }
}

.landing1 {
  font-size: 120%;
}

.landing2 {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.landing3 {
  color: #a60000;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: I've got it to work using IE11.  It looks like there is an issue downloading css\mycss.css file.  Try clearing your cache and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of stuff, and succeeded in isolating the problem, the problem is the .container class, for some reason, everything that is inside of a `<div class="container"></div>` isn't showing. when i remove that class it's working fine (but I need that class for the layout).